# Implement PHP's static array in angular 2

Tags: php, arrays, angular, static, constants

I want to implement a static array in angular 2 equivalent to this one in PHP. How can I do that?

```
 <?php
 class Services
 {
     const TaskPoll         =   "TaskPoll";
     const ModuleList       =   "ModuleList";

     public static $services = array
     (
        Services::TaskPoll              =>array("APIURL"=>"task/poll","APIRequestType"=>"PostAPI","RestService"=>["WarName"=>"abc","ServiceUrl"=>"http://localhost:8080"]),
        Services::ModuleList            =>array("APIURL"=>"task/modulelist","APIRequestType"=>"GetAPI","RestService"=>["WarName"=>"abc","ServiceUrl"=>"http://localhost:8080"]),
     );
 }
```

Comment: Why you are writing the code in `PHP` and `Angualr 2`? I mean the above code

Comment: @Mr_Perfect I need to have the same code ported in angular 2. thats why

Answer (score 0):

```
class Services {
  public static readonly TaskPoll = 'TaskPoll';
  public static readonly ModuleList = 'ModuleList';

  public static readonly $services = {
    TaskPoll: {'APIURL': 'task/poll', 'APIRequestType': 'PostAPI', 'RestService': {'WarName': 'abc', 'ServiceUrl': 'http://localhost:8080'}},
    ModuleList: {'APIURL': 'task/modulelist', 'APIRequestType': 'GetAPI', 'RestService': {'WarName': 'abc', 'ServiceUrl': 'http://localhost:8080'}}
  };
}

console.log(Services.$services.TaskPoll);
```